# What happens to the Eigen values and Eigen vectors of a matrix when it is rotated?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I have a matrix $\textbf{A}$ with Eigenvectors $\textbf{x1,x2..}$ corresponding to the Eigenvalues $\lambda1, \lambda2...$

If I am rotating this matrix $\textbf{A}$ by $\theta$ degrees, what happens to the Eigenvalues and the Eigenvectors? Is there any relationship between them before and after the rotation?

Comment: What do you mean rotating $A$ by a rotation $R$ ? Does this mean you do a change of basis i.e a conjugation $R^{-1}AR$ or just a multiplication on left $RA$ or right $AR$ ?

Comment: By rotation, I meant a linear transformation on A by a rotation matrix ie., $A.R$

Comment: Why you don't try it with 2x2 with some software? I've tried it with 2x2 real matrix and Matlab yields different eigenvalues and eigenvectors before and after.

Comment: @CroCo Yes. I too tried in MATLAB. Got different eigenvalues and different eigenvectors. But I am in the hope that some kind of relationship exists between the eigenvalues/vectors of the original matrix and those of the rotated matrix.

Answer (score 0):

I do not suspect you will have any simple relationship. Take the simplest example:
$A=I_2$, the identity matrix in two dimensions, which has all vectors as eigenvectors with the eigenvalue $1$. Let $R$ be the rotation by an angle of $\theta$, i.e. $$R=\begin{pmatrix}\cos\theta & -\sin\theta\\
\sin\theta& \cos\theta\end{pmatrix}.$$
If we are acting on the real plane $\mathbb{R}^2$, we see that $AR=R$ does not have any eigenvectors or eigenvalues. Going to the complex case, the eigenvalues will be $e^{\pm i\theta}$. Note in particular that we are going from one eigenvalue to two. Hopefully this illustrates the difficulties, although I have not proven that there cannot be some kind of relationship.